# How to output trailing zero in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Please, consider the following code:

```
class Book
  def initialize (price)
   @price=price
  end

  def book_price
   puts "Price: #{@price}"
  end
end

book1=Book.new(19.60)
book1.book_price
```

It always returns "Price:19.6" instead of "Price:19.60"

I have tried changing `@price=price.to_f`, but it made no difference.
How can I keep the trailing zero without converting to string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25):

```
def book_price
  "Price: %.2f" % @price
end
```

Comment: Beat me to it, while I was looking up the documentation link :)